# Actionscript 3: Event.SOUND_COMPLETE doesn't fire

Tags: actionscript-3, audio-player

Okay, so i was working on my simple actionscript-3 sound player for a website I'm making...
and while doing so it occured to me that the SOUND_COMPLETE event doesn't fire for some reason. So if anyone seems to notice the problem in my code, please respond!

```
package {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.external.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class player{

        private var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
        private var sound:Sound;
        private var lastPosition:Number = 0;

        public function player():void{
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("load", this.load);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("play", this.play);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("stop", this.stop);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("reset", this.reset);
        }
        /*
        javascript from inside actionscript:

            ExternalInterface.call("console.log","ipsum");
        */
        private function load(url:String):void{
            var audio:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            try {
                this.soundChannel.stop();
            } catch(e:Error) {
            };
            this.sound = new Sound();
            this.sound.load(audio);
            this.lastPosition = 0;
        }
        private function play():void{
            this.soundChannel = this.sound.play(this.lastPosition);
            this.soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,finished);
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log","started playing");
        }
        private function finished():void{
            this.lastPosition=0;
            this.soundChannel=this.sound.play()
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log","finished playing");
        }
        private function reset():void{
            this.lastPosition = 0;
            this.soundChannel.stop();
        }
        private function stop():void{
            try {
                this.lastPosition = this.soundChannel.position;
                this.soundChannel.stop();
            } catch(e:Error) {
            };
        }

    }
}//package
```

Comment: http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2009/10/14/as3-pitfalls-sound_complete-event-is-not-firing/

Comment: That doesn't apply for me in this case, since everytime i use the play function it adds the EventListener again.
Thanks for replying though!

Comment: I think you should call your local stop function in load, and I think you're getting a runtime error in your finished() function, because it is incapable of accepting the event it would be passed. The runtime error is preventing the resto of your code from running. I can only assume you're not seeing it because you've disabled debugging or are not running it in the debug player.

Comment: Does the SOUND_COMPLETE never fire ? or just sometimes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `finished()` doesn't accept an event, it should be :

```
    private function finished(e:Event):void{
        this.lastPosition=0;
        this.soundChannel=this.sound.play()
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log","finished playing");
    }
```